# How Delete Spam Users from Cognito User Pool (AWS CLI in Bash)

Tags: jquery, bash

My cognito user pool has accumulated some spam which I'd like to clean up. My plan is to use AWS CLI in bash to search for suspect accounts, and delete them once I'm happy with the script. Here's where I've got to:

```
#!/bin/bash

COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID="XXXXXXXX"

# list all cognito accounts 
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id $COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID --filter 'email^="test"' | 
jq -r '.Users | .[] | .Username' |
while read uname1; do
  echo "Deleting $uname1";
 # aws cognito-idp admin-delete-user --user-pool-id $COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID --username $uname1;
 aws cognito-idp admin-get-user --user-pool-id $COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID --username $uname1;
done
```

This seems to run fine up until the admin-get-user command, where for some reason the format of the username is not right:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the AdminGetUser operation: 1 validation error detected: Value at 'username' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\p{L}\p{M}\p{S}\p{N}\p{P}]+
```

**Notes**

If I put it inside single quotes it passes, but the user is not recognised.
If I comment out the while loop, I see the list of user names. And they look fine.

Any clues how to fix this?